# Is NULL arguments a bad practice?

Tags: java, exception, methods, null, arguments

Is it a bad practice to pass NULL argument to methods or in other words should we have method definitions which allow NULL argument as valid argument.

Suppose i want two method
1. to retrieve list of all of companies
2. to retrieve list of companies based upon filter.

We can either have two methods like as below

```
    List<Company> getAllCompaniesList();
    List<Company> getCompaniesList(Company companyFilter);
```

or we can have one single method

```
    List<Company> getCompaniesList(Company companyFilter);
```

here in second case, if argument is NULL then method return list of all of companies.

Beside question of good practice practically i see one more issue with later approach which is explained below.

I am implementing Spring AOP, in which i want to have some checks on arguments like
1. Is argument NULL ?
2. is size of collection 0?

There are some scenarios where we can not have null argument at all like for method

```
    void addBranches(int companyId, List<Branch>);
```

This check can be performed very well by using Spring AOP by defining method like following

```
@Before(argNames="args", value="execution(* *)")
void beforeCall(JoinPoint joinPoint ,Object[] args )
{ 
           foreach(Object obj in args)
           {
                 if(obj == NULL)
                 {
                     throw new Exception("Argument NULL");
                 } 
           }   
}
```

But problem i am facing is since i have defined some of methods which should accept NULL argument for multiple functionality of one single method as mentioned above for method  List getCompaniesList(Company companyFilter);
So i can not apply AOP uniformly for all of methods and neither some expression for methods name match will be useful here.

Please let me know if more information is required or problem is not descriptive enough.

Thanks for reading my problem and giving thought upon it.

Comment: It's a matter of style. No single right answer.

Comment: I believe the dilemma starts with: "accept NULL argument for multiple functionality of one single method", each method should do just one think. In your example I Will prefer send a list of filters, and an empty list should have the same effect that sending null in your method.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's fine, in cases when there are too many overloaded methods. So instead of having all combinations of parameters, you allow some of them to be `null`. But if you do so, document this explicitly with

```
@param foo foo description. Can be null
```

In your case I'd have the two methods, where the first one invokes the second with a `null` argument. It makes the API more usable.

There is no strict line where to stop overloading and where to start relying on nullable parameters. It's a matter of preference. But note that thus your method with the most params will allow some of them to be nullable, so document this as well.

---

Also note that a preferred way to cope with multiple constructor parameters is via a Builder. So instead of:

```
public Foo(String bar, String baz, int fooo, double barr, String asd);
```

where each of the arguments is optional, you can have:

```
Foo foo = new FooBuilder().setBar(bar).setFooo(fooo).build();
```

Comment: But, then we have to create one method per parameter (unless we group some parameters into an object, eg. string username, string password = object user). It is useful & pretty, but isn't it too much code ? Also, henning77 says its not okay from a practical perspective due to all the NPEs it could cause.

Answer (score 22):

I use a very simple rule:

**Never allow null as an argument or return value on a public method.**

I make use of [Optional](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained) and [Preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) or AOP to enforce that rule.
This decision already saved me tons of hours bugfixing after NPE's or strange behaviour.

Comment: Great links!  As an experienced programmer just gaining more literacy in Java, this is very useful.

Comment: `setLocationRelativeTo(null);` ... I wish Sun/Oracle knew it is a bad practice.

Comment: But Bozho says its okay to allow null arguments sometimes. Would you agree ?

Comment: Optional ist just another kind of NULL. If you're serious about this, you shouldn't use Optional either

Answer (score 8):

It's common practice, but there are ways of making your code clearer - avoiding null checks in sometimes, or moving them elsewhere. Look up the null object pattern - it may well be exactly what you need: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern?wasRedirected=true

Comment: Thanks, Can u please provide some good links for same if you already know?

Comment: Null object pattern can be useful for some of scenarios like returning collection not in all cases like in case its single object i will return NULL.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is: simple interface, complicated implementation.

Design decisions about your API should be made by considering how the client code is likely to use it.  If you expect to see either

```
getAllCompaniesList(null);
```

or

```
if (companyFilter == null) {
    getAllCompaniesList();
} else {
    getAllCompaniesList(companyFilter);
}
```

then you're doing it wrong.  If the likely use-case is that the client code will, at the time it is written, either have or not have a filter, you should supply two entry points; if that decision is likely not made until run-time, allow a null argument.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach that may be workable may be to have a `CompanyFilter` interface with an `companyIsIncluded(Company)` method that accepts a `Company` and returns true or false to say whether any company should be included.  `Company` could implement the interface so that `companyIsIncluded` method's behavior mirrored `equals()`, but one could easily have a singleton `CompanyFilter.AllCompanies` whose `companyIsIncluded()` method would always return true.  Using that approach, there's no need to pass a null value--just pass a reference to the `AllComapnies` singleton.